# Combinatorial analysis using a prime list

Tags: analysis, prime-numbers

I ran across a puzzle and I would like to know if you guys could help me out. Let's suppose I've got a list with 2000000 prime numbers and there is a number (let's call it N) which is a product of two primes (P, Q)

I wanted to know how many possible combinations there could be testing each possibility, I know it is something related to combinatorial analysis but I am afraid I am not confident in this subject

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you going to try all possible pairs with $P$ and $Q$ any of those prime numbers? Or are you going to always take $P\leq Q$? Or are you going to consider only $P\leq Q\leq \sqrt{N}$? Other?

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you have $k$ primes then there are $\binom k2=\frac {k(k+1)}2$ pairs of them.  Is that what you are asking?  Of course, in your case you can rule out lots of cases (if $N$ is very large you can skip $2\times 3$ and so on).

Comment: @lulu $N$ could potentially be a square too.

Comment: Thanks for answering, guys! So basically I would try all the possible combinations. let's say N = 10. Then I want to find two prime numbers that generated N. Then I would start off by testing (2*3, 2*5) and so on

Comment: Now lets say N = 25; then I would have to test (2*2, 2*3, 2*5, 2*7, ... until 5*2, 5*3, 5*5

Comment: Well, from your example it looks like you are always looking at pairs of primes $(P,Q)$ with $P\leq Q\leq\sqrt{N}$. Then that would be $\binom{[\sqrt{N}]}{2}+[\sqrt{N}]$, where I am denoting by $[\sqrt{N}]$ the number of primes in your list that are $\leq \sqrt{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice a few things:

- We can choose any of the two primes with repetition.
- There are $2,000,000$ primes.
- The order of the primes doesn't matter, since multiplicative commutes ($a\cdot b = b \cdot a$).

This is identical to a selection with repetition problem: choosing $2$ primes from $2,000,000$ primes, with repetition.

Thus, we can use binomial coefficients with this. In general, if we have $n$ objects and want to choose from them $k$ objects, the number of such selections is given by

$$\binom{n+k-1}{k} \;\;\; \text{or, equivalently,} \;\;\; \binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$$

Here, $n=2,000,000$ and $k=2$. Thus, using the former formulation for simplicity:

$$\binom{n+k-1}{k} = \binom{2,000,000 + 2 - 1}{2} = \binom{2,000,001}{2} = \frac{2,000,001 \cdot 2,000,000}{2}$$

This is $2,000,000,100,000$ - two trillion, one hundred thousand in American units.

---

*Thanks to Thomas Andrews for pointing this out in the comments.*

As a follow-up regarding the intuition behind this method, this is generally known as the "stars and bars" method and is discussed, among other places, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out, how did you come up with the answer, I would like to learn the logic behind that

Comment: Just kind of common sense I guess. Imagine instead you only had a smaller amount of primes, say $3$ of them. You could enumerate the number of possibilities by using a tree diagram and counting how many branches at at the end. In this case since there aren't any limitations you would just end up drawing three branches, then three from each of those, for a total of nine. This isn't directly tied to combinatorial analysis in that it's often taught in grade school (you probably just forgot :p), there's not really any hardcore mathematics underlying this at that skill level.

Comment: ... good point, I'll fix that

Comment: @ThomasAndrews -- Okay, sorry about the oversight, I fixed my post accordingly.